# What is the use of bit fields in a struct?

Tags: c++, c

Bit fields in a structure can be used to save some bytes of memory, I have heard. How can we use this particular bytes for any purposes?

```
typedef struct
{
     char A : 1;
     int  B : 1;
} Struct1;
```

Comment: can anyone explain how can these "saved bytes" of memory used fruitfully.......

Comment: Note that since you didn't specify `unsigned` on the types, the only portable value that can be stored in those bits is 0; it is not clear whether the other value is 1 or -1 (it would be -1 if the fields were explicitly `signed`, but a compiler can treat types with sign qualification as signed or unsigned — an implementation defined behaviour.  Actually, almost everything about bit fields is implementation defined.  The most common reason to use them is not to save space, but to match a data structure to the bit layout of the registers in some memory-mapped device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In embedded systems, the bit fields in a structure can be used to represent bit fields or a hardware device.

Other uses for bit fields are in protocols (messages).  One byte (or 4 bytes) to represent the presences or absences of many things would occupy a lot a space and wasted transmission time.  So in 1 byte you could represent 8 Boolean conditions rather than using 8 bytes or 8 words to do so.

The bit fields in a structure are usually used as convenience.  The same operations to extract, set or test bit fields can be performed using the arithmetic bit operators (such as AND).

Comment: I was seeking answer in embedded system context. thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 4):

The `char` value itself with a width of one bit is not particularly useful.  In fact `char` values as bit fields are not standard.  It's an extension that Microsoft added.  On the other hand the `B` field can be used as on / off value since it can hold the values 1 or 0

```
Struct1 s;
s.B = 0;
if (s.B) { 
  ... 
}
```

This particular example doesn't really demonstrate the savings offered by bit fields particularly well.  Need a more complex strut for that.  Consider the following

```
typedef struct { 
  int Value1;
  int Value2;
} S1;
```

On most platforms `S1` will have a size of 8 (each `int` field being 4 bytes long).  Imagine though that `Value1` and `Value2` will always have values between 0 and 10.  This could be stored in 4 bits but we're using 32 bits meaning.  Using bit fields we could reduce the waste significantly here

```
typedef struct { 
  int Value1 : 4;
  int Value2 : 4;
} S1;
```

Now the size of `S1` is likely 1 byte and can still hold all of the necessary values

Answer (score 0):

Saving memory means, that you need less memory. This can increase the program performance due to less swapping or cache misses.

In your example the two parts A and B would be stored in a byte (or whatever the compiler decides to use), instead of two. A better example is, if you want to store the occupied seats in an opera house with 1000 seats. If you would store them as a boolean which is often stored in a byte per boolean, they could be stored in 128 bytes, because per seat only one bit is needed.

The downside is the performance loss. Accessing the bits need some additional shifting or xor-ing. Thus, it's a trade-off memory for computation time.